# Errors trying to execute a Metasploit script

Tags: kali-linux, metasploit

I'm trying to run [this exploit](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/9926/) in Metasploit on Kali Linux. I have the file in the exploit folder, I just need to execute the script, but I'm getting some errors. This is the description from the website:

```
# 18
Info -> CorePlugin: TinyMCE TinyBrowser addon multiple vulnerabilities 
Versions effected: Joomla! 1.5.12 
Check: /plugins/editors/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/tinybrowser/
Exploit: While Joomla! team announced only File Upload vulnerability, in fact there are many. See: http://www.milw0rm.com/exploits/9296
Vulnerable? Yes
```

Comment: Don't offer payment, we are a free site and don't suggest alternative communication methods (use chat for that).

Answer (score 0):

Since the exploit is pretty outdated, it should be already available in your metasploit database. You don't have to copy that exploit to your metasploit, just search for it: msf > search TinyMCE. If you still get errors, add them to your question.